# Android Main Screen glitch on Rapberry Pi3

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, mainscreen

I'm beginner in Android OS development and I tried to compile Android 6.0.1 from here: https://github.com/peyo-hd/device_brcm_rpi3/tree/npv
And everything was fine until I installed it on my Raspberry. I faced with some glitches on the Main screen.

[image]

When I run application the image is OK. 
And sometimes the blue frame blinks when an application is closing.

I even tried to install the other Launcher apk, but got the same problem.

I suspect the problem is in OpenGL but still not sure.
I'm just wondering what do I call this effect and what could be cause of this.

Thank you in advance for any answer.